# Eclipse Jetty to Mortbay Jetty

Tags: heroku, jetty

I have eclipse jetty configured

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0.v20131115</version>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <webApp>
                <contextPath>/websockets</contextPath>
              </webApp>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Now I want to deploy it to Heroku. I change plugin to Mortbay Jetty

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>7.5.4.v20111024</version>
                                <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The apps starts but the contextPath is not set to /websockets. How can i configure Mortbay Jetty's contextPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.mortbay.jetty` is for Jetty 6 and older.  (**DO NOT USE Jetty 6**, it was EOL'd back in early 2010, and has no security or web updates since then)

(History Lesson)
Starting with Jetty 7, the project moved to the Eclipse Foundation, hence the name `org.eclipse.jetty`.  Jetty 7 was the first version of Jetty to implement WebSocket drafts.  The API evolved over the entire course of Jetty 7, and Jetty 8 and has decent (however partial/incomplete) support for WebSocket.
The WebSocket implementation (APIs and Protocol) was heavily refactored in Jetty 9 to support the finalized RFC-6455 (WebSocket Protocol), along with WebSocket extensions, and adding support for JSR-356 (Java WebSocket API).

You should also not mix versions of Jetty, you have Jetty runner at version 7.5.4, and jetty-maven-plugin at 9.1.0 - that will never work.

That being said, here's the 2 XML fragments of most use to you.

*jetty-maven-plugin*

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/websockets</contextPath>
        </webApp>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*jetty-runner*

```xml
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
    <destFileName>jetty-runner.jar</destFileName>
</artifactItem>
```